# Como puedo hacer un programa en Java para contar todos los caracteres repetidos en un texto muy largo, y no línea por línea, sino todo el texto

Tags: java, txt, caracteres, texto, sumatoria

Estoy haciendo un programa en Java que cuente los caracteres repetidos de un texto que está en un archivo. Necesito saber cuantas veces se repite cada letra, pero también cada espacio, cada signo de puntuación, cada salto de linea...

Consigo que cuente los caracteres correctamente, pero de cada una de las líneas por separado, y yo quiero totalizar las repeticiones de todo el texto completo. Es decir, que me sume lo que hay en cada línea.

Si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradecería mucho.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
package caracteresrepetidos;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 *
 * @author Frami
 */
public class Caracteresrepetidos {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // BufferedReader archivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ecoli.fa"));        
        BufferedReader archivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("don-quixote.txt"));
        String caracteres;
        
        while((caracteres = archivo.readLine()) != null) {
                HashMap <Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();         
                char[] letras = caracteres.toCharArray();

                for (char key : letras){
                    if(map.containsKey(key)){
                        map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
                    }else{
                        map.put(key, 1);
                    }
                
                }

        System.out.println("Caracteres = " + map);
        }
    }
}
```

Este es un fragmento del texto que analizo:

"DON QUIXOTE

by Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra

Translated by John Ormsby

VOLUME I.

CHAPTER I.

WHICH TREATS OF THE CHARACTER AND PURSUITS OF THE FAMOUS GENTLEMAN DON
QUIXOTE OF LA MANCHA"

Y el resultado que obtengo con mi código es este:

Caracteres = { =1, Q=1, D=1, T=1, U=1, E=1, X=1, I=1, N=1, O=2}

Caracteres = {}

Caracteres = { =4, a=4, b=1, C=1, d=2, e=5, g=1, i=1, l=1, M=1, n=1, r=2, s=1, S=1, t=1, u=1, v=2, y=1}

Caracteres = {}

Caracteres = { =3, a=2, b=2, d=1, e=1, h=1, J=1, l=1, m=1, n=2, o=1, O=1, r=2, s=2, T=1, t=1, y=2}

Caracteres = {}

Caracteres = { =1, U=1, E=1, V=1, I=1, L=1, M=1, .=1, O=1}

Caracteres = {}

Caracteres = {P=1,  =1, A=1, R=1, C=1, T=1, E=1, H=1, I=1, .=1}

Caracteres = {}

Caracteres = { =11, A=6, C=3, D=2, E=6, F=3, G=1, H=5, I=2, L=1, M=2, N=4, O=4, P=1, R=4, S=4, T=7, U=3, W=1}

Caracteres = { =3, A=3, C=1, E=1, F=1, H=1, I=1, L=1, M=1, N=1, O=2, Q=1, T=1, U=1, X=1}

Busco obtener 1 sola línea de resultado que sume los caracteres de las 12 líneas analizadas en el ejemplo.

Comment: Si creas el map justo antes del while debería funcionar lo que quieres

Comment: He seguido tus instrucciones y ha funcionado !!!! 
Muchas gracias